# Calculations are wrong in my homework code.  How to fix?

Tags: c++, debugging

Here's what I'm supposed to do:

- Write a base class Worker and 2 derived classes `HourlyWorker` and `SalariedWorker`. Every worker has a name and salary rate.
- Write a virtual function `compute_pay(int hours)` that computes the weekly pay for every worker. Hourly worker gets pay in full for the first 40 hours and haft the rate for any hours over that. The salaried worker gets paid the hourly wage for 40 hours, no matter what the actual number of hours is.

And below is my code, which compiles without error. But the calculations are all wrong. I hope someone can tell me what's wrong with my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//////////// Worker /////////////////////////////
class Worker
{
    public:
        Worker();
        Worker(string name, int salary);
        void print();
        int compute_pay(int hours);
        string get_name();
        int get_salary();
    private:
        string name;
        int salary;
        int payout;
};

Worker::Worker() {salary = 0;}
Worker::Worker(string name, int salary)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->salary = salary;
}
void Worker::print()
{
    cout << "Worker name: " << this->name;
    cout << "Salary: " << this->salary;
}
int Worker::compute_pay(int hours)
{
    this->payout = this->salary * hours;
    return payout;
}
string Worker::get_name() {return this->name;}

int Worker::get_salary() { return this->salary;}
//////////// HourlyWorker ///////////////////////
class HourlyWorker : public Worker
{
    public:
    HourlyWorker(string name, int salary);
    int compute_pay(int hours); 
private:
    string name;
    int salary;
    int payout;
};

HourlyWorker::HourlyWorker(string name, int salary)
    :Worker(name, salary) {}

int HourlyWorker::compute_pay(int hours)
{
    int temp = 0;
    if (hours >= 40)
    {
        temp = (this->salary * (hours - 40)) / 2;
        this->payout = (this->salary * 40) + temp;
    }
    else
    {
        this->payout = this->salary * hours;
    }
    return payout;
}
//////////// SalariedWorker /////////////////////
class SalariedWorker : public Worker
{
    public:
        SalariedWorker(string name, int salary);
        int compute_pay(int hours); 
    private:
        string name;
        int salary;
        int payout;
};

SalariedWorker::SalariedWorker(string name, int salary)
    :Worker(name, salary) {}

int SalariedWorker::compute_pay(int hours)
{
    this->payout = this->salary * 40;
    return payout;
}
///////// 

int main()
{
    HourlyWorker a("Sam", 20);
    HourlyWorker b("Mary", 15);
    SalariedWorker c("Tom", 30);
    SalariedWorker d("Pat", 40);

    cout << "Hourly worker " << a.get_name() << " earns $"
         << a.get_salary();
    cout << " and worked 20 hours for a pay of $" << a.compute_pay(20)
         << "\n";
    cout << "Hourly worker " << b.get_name() << " earns $"
         << b.get_salary();
    cout << " and worked 50 hours for a pay of $" << b.compute_pay(50)
         << "\n";
    cout << "Salaried worker " << c.get_name() << " earns $"
         << c.get_salary();
    cout << " and worked 20 hours for a pay of $" << c.compute_pay(20)
         << "\n";
    cout << "Salaried worker " << d.get_name() << " earns $"
         << d.get_salary();
    cout << " and worked 50 hours for a pay of $" << d.compute_pay(50)
         << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This is the result when i run it:

> ```
> Hourly worker Sam earns $20 and worked 20 hours for a pay of $85081400
> Hourly worker Mary earns $15 and worked 50 hours for a pay of $-1915569464
> Salaried worker Tom earns $30 and worked 20 hours for a pay of $91731520
> Salaried worker Pat earns $40 and worked 50 hours for a pay of $162529280
> ```

and this is what i suppose to get

> ```
> Hourly worker Sam earns $20 and worked 20 hours for a pay of $400
> Hourly worker Mary earns $15 and worked 50 hours for a pay of $825
> Salaried worker Tom earns $30 and worked 20 hours for a pay of $1200
> Salaried worker Pat earns $40 and worked 50 hours for a pay of $2000
> ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of problems in your code. The reason you're seeing such odd numbers in your calculations is because each of your derived classes (`HourlyWorker` and `SalariedWorker`) have their own private `name`, `salary` and `payout` members.  These members are *not* the same as the `name`, `salary` and `payout` members in the base class, because derived classes do not have direct access to private members.

So, why the odd numbers?  It's because you only ever set `salary` by calling the base class constructor.  That sets the base class' private `salary` member, but *not* the derived class member.  Thus, the derived class member is just whatever happened to be at that location in memory, so when you multiply it by the number of hours worked, you get a very odd result.

You can fix that by making the data members protected in the base class, and removing them from the derived class definitions.  (Name can still be private since you don't directly access it in the derived classes.)  That way, when you access `salary`, you'll always be accessing the base class member, which will have the correct value.

Once you fix that, you should see reasonable numbers.  However, your expected values don't square with the assignment definition that you gave, as far as I can tell.  You'll have to sort that out on your own.

In addition to that, you were asked to write a *virtual* function, but your `compute_pay` function is not actually virtual.  A good overview of virtual functions in C++ is available [in the C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html), so I strongly suggest that you take a look at that.  In brief, though, the difference is that if you call a virtual function on a base class pointer or reference which is actually of a derived type, the appropriate derived class function will be called.  If the function is non-virtual, the base class function will always be called, even if the derived class overrides it.

Answer (score -2):

Actually the salary of the employee is always saved to the worker class not in the hourly and salaried class. so whenever u call "compute_pay" it uses the garbage value. so to remove that use this in your constructor of both hourly and salaried class.

```
SalariedWorker::SalariedWorker(string name, int salary)
:Worker(name, salary) {this->salary=salary;}

HourlyWorker::HourlyWorker(string name, int salary)
:Worker(name, salary) {this->salary=salary;}

this->salary=salary
```

copy the salary to these class salary too.

Comment: That's the wrong way to go about it.  There's no need to duplicate data across the class hierarchy; doing so is poor design and will inevitably result in problems.

Comment: just put cout in ur hourlyworker class and salaried worker class and print this->salary . u will get garbage value. and during calculations u are using  these garbage values.

Comment: @Mitch Lindgren Also if this is the wrong way then why he created salaray,name,compute_pay in each and every class. He created this just to keep copy of all data . So i did that.

Comment: No, he added those member variables to each derived class because he doesn't understand how inheritance in C++ works.